# JQL Selecting all Epics that have no stories

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to figure out how to create a select that would bring up all empty epics (those that have no stories in them) so I could easily tell which ones need filling.

Selecting stories that have or do NOT have an epic link is easy. I can not seem to find a way to search the other way around.

This is where I am right now:

```
issuetype = Epic AND project = projectname AND Issues in Epic is EMPTY
```

The part after the last `AND` is what I need the code to do and can not seem to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not support with JQL out of the box, but there are a few add-ons that do provide support for this.

The most common one is the [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/cloud/overview) which comes with a number of [additional JQL functions](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html) like [hasLinkType](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_haslinktype), that you can use for your scenario in a query like this:

```
project = PROJECT and issuetype = Epic and issueFunction not in hasLinkType("Epic-Story Link")
```

Comment: I thought that would be the case.  Thanks for the add-on suggestion.